# Protected operators by SUSY

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry, conformal-field-theory

People say that

> In superconformal field theories with extended susy (say 4d, $\mathcal{N}=2$) we have protected local operators
>   annihilated by some supercharges $Q_I$. Also, upon breaking conformal
>   symmetry there is a well defined particle spectrum which contains in
>   particular BPS states.

I am not sure I understand the term "protected". Protected operators against what? Also, how and why these operators lead to BPS states? I know that the latter are annihilated by half or quarter the supersymmetries, but again why **protected**?

Is there a simple example of such an operator $\mathcal{O}$ where it is  obvious that
$$
Q \mathcal{O} =0?
$$

Comment: What people? Source?

Comment: Heard it today in a talk. But I think it is written in many papers.